Volume control not working for Web App in iOS but works well for android phones
I'm facing an issue with volume control in my Ionic React web app. While I can mute or unmute audio, I can't adjust the volume level, issue only persists in iOS. Has anyone encountered this limitation in [Ionic] React applications, and if so, what solutions or workarounds have you found?
This is what I return
<div className="volume">
    <IonRange value={volume} onIonChange={handleVolumeChange} />
    <IonLabel slot="end">{`${volume}%`}</IonLabel>
</div>

And this is how I handle the volume change
const handleVolumeChange = (event: CustomEvent) => {
        const newVolume = event.detail.value as number;
        if (audioRef.current) {
            audioRef.current.volume = newVolume / 100;
            setVolume(newVolume);
            // console.log("Selected volume:", newVolume);

            const auth = getAuth();
            const user = auth.currentUser;
            if (user) {
                updateUserPreference(user.uid, { volume: newVolume });
            }
        }
    };

